# Alternative way of printing multidimensional array row elements

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Is there an alternative way to print Multidimensional Array Row Elements in Java? I am having trouble with how to print the Multidimensional array elements rows, since the requirements is quite different.

For Example instead of:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

The output would be:

```
Contents of row 1 : 1 2
Contents of row 2 : 3 4
Contents of row 3 : 5 6
```

Here is my code I tried doing

```
"Contents of row " +(i+1)+ " : " +arr[i][j]+"
```

but it does not quite fit on what I was aiming for. The output becomes:

```
Contents of row 1 : 1  Contents of row 1 : 2
Contents of row 2 : 3  Contents of row 2 : 4
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestH13 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // initialize here.
        int row, col, i, j;
        int[][] arr = new int[100][100];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // enter row and column for array.
        System.out.print("How many rows: ");
        row = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("How many columns: ");
        col = input.nextInt();

        // enter array elements.
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.print("Enter element a[" + i + "][" + j + "] : ");
                arr[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        // print the array elements
        System.out.println("Elements in the array");
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.print(
                        "Contents of row " + (i + 1) + " : " + arr[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just move the `"Contents of row: n"` part out of the inner loop:

```java
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    System.out.print("Contents of row " + (i + 1) + " :");
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        System.out.print(" " + arr[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

at the first I changed the location of 2d array initialization after getting the number of rows and columns, secondly I divided your print section in 2 part one at the entry of row and second in each column:

```
int row, col, i, j;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// enter row and column for array.
System.out.print("How many rows: ");
row = input.nextInt();
System.out.print("How many columns: ");
col = input.nextInt();

int[][] arr = new int[row][col];

// enter array elements.
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        System.out.print("Enter element a[" + i + "][" + j + "] : ");
        arr[i][j] = input.nextInt();
    }
}

// print the array elements
System.out.println("Elements in the array");
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    System.out.print("Contents of row " + (i + 1) + " : ");
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the rows as follows:

```java
int[][] arr = {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
        {5, 6}};

IntStream
        // iterate over indices of the rows
        .range(0, arr.length)
        // for each row
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays
                // iterate over elements of the row
                .stream(arr[i])
                // string representation of the element
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                // join contents of the row into one
                // line with a space " " delimiter
                // and a certain prefix and suffix
                .collect(Collectors.joining(
                        " ", // delimiter
                        "Contents of row " + (i + 1) + " : ", // prefix
                        "" // suffix
                )))
        // output line by line
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
Contents of row 1 : 1 2
Contents of row 2 : 3 4
Contents of row 3 : 5 6
```